# Is it possible to give users different roles/profiles on different part of the website?

Tags: users

For example, is it possible to give *userA* full read/write access on some part but read-only access on others?

Most importantly, is this possible without too much hassle? I mean what I'm  looking for is some sort of "inheritance", i.e.  if I give *userA* full read/write access on *nodeA*, I'd like those exact same rights are granted to *userA* on every child node of *nodeA*, recursively.

I've seen Flexi Access but this module does not seem to satisfy my "inheritance" constraint.

Answer (score 2):

A widely accepted solution for this would be using the [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module.

With this module, you can define different access settings and local roles for a given group type, and for all the nodes associated to it (this would be the "inheritance" you are looking for).

It is not the simplest module to use, though. You can find some "getting started" documentation here: https://www.drupal.org/node/861418

Answer (score 0):

Another solution for this would be using the [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module, which is getting accepted more and more (an [Organic groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) alternative ...).

[Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) allows for creating arbitrary collections of your content and users on your site, and grant access control permissions on those collections. It is available as of D7, and has a D8 version also. The [Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/group) module creates groups as entities, making them fully fieldable, extensible and exportable.

For more details about the various roles and permissions, refer to my answer to "[What are the various roles supported by the Group module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197493)".

## Resources

- [Community documentation for the Group module](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666972).
- Video tutorial "[How to use the Group module in Drupal 8 to manage editorial access control to different areas of a web site](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=GkiCLJk5n0s)".

**Note**: I can't wait for somebody to (re-)create [group](/questions/tagged/group).